# Partitioning Issues using GParted with Linux

Tags: partitioning, mount, gparted

I'm currently having issues in creating a new partition within the Linux environment.

Currently, I've enrolled myself in the Security Tube Python Scripting Expert course, however when I created my VM on Virtual Box, I assigned only 8GB of disk space and forgot to change it.

Now, I'm currently sitting at 100% usage. I've currently assigned 40.83GiB of free unallocated space to the virtual disk space, however I've assigned it to the FAT32 File System instead of ext4 which currently has that 8GB of disk space (which currently holds all my Python course material.

The partition name for ext4 is - /dev/sda1. It's mount point is named as : /

I was wanting to see if I should do the following:

1. Format the file system that I assigned to fat32 to ext4 so it's the same as the 7.5GiB
2. From there unmount the 40.83GiB to the same mount point as /dev/sda1 which is the same as the 7.5GiB

I have asked a lot of people at work if they know how to carry out these tasks, they have said that I should run parted magic to doing any partitioning.

Comment: it was better to upload gparted screenshot.

Comment: It won't allow me too, as I tried attaching a screenshot of what the virtual hard disk looks like.

It states that I need 10 reputation to do a post with an image attached

Comment: which was your host os?If it was linux then install shutter and take a screenshot of gparted.After that upload the screenshot to imgur.com then provide the link here.

Comment: On Virtual Box it's - Ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS Desktop Version
Guest OS - Windows 8

Cheers will do.

Comment: Here's the link: http://i.imgur.com/gAwcuSz.png

Comment: If I can't find a solution by Friday, then I'm going to go old school by deleting the VM and starting all over again and re-install everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've removed the VM from VirtualBox altogether and started all over again.

As no help was given since posting this question, the only way forward was to start all over again. The good thing is: I'm now running with more space than actually required.